# Form Submit on dropdown change event Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form like this

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" name="search-page">

    <div class="rowElem">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="" value="Appliances"  />
        <label>Appliances</label>
    </div>
    <div class="rowElem">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="" value="Electronics and Computers"  />
        <label>Electronics and Computers</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sear htnew" name="analyse" value="Analyse" id="analyseSubmit" />

    <select name="chartType" id="chartName">
        <option value="1333" selected>Product Year</option>
        <option value="1334" >Category Year</option>
        <option value="1335" >Material Year</option>


    </select>

</form>
```

I need to submit  the form when change the dropdown value.

i tried something like

```
$(function () {
        $("#chartName").change(function (e) {
            $('#searchform').submit();
        });

});
```

but it is not submitting .can any one help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it still not submitting?

Comment: No..................................

Comment: have you attached JQuery.js file?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `$` in front of the form selector, so the submit method is called on a string which is resulting in an error

```
$(function () {
    $("#chartName").change(function (e) {
        //missing $ here
        $('#searchform').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry here is my mistake.I already addend in my code.but not working.

Comment: @Arun looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cvpzs/1/ - can you help reproducing the error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an "action" on your form for the submit. I'm assuming you have some sort of handling for the form, so you need something like:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" name="search-page" action="/go/to/success.html">
```